# Hey I think there is something wrong with step up transformer

Tags: electric-current

In our physics textbooks it is said that in the step up transformer the number of coils in the secondary solenoid is more than that in the primary one. However, it is also told that that induced emf depends on the magnitude of magnetic field. More the magnitude of the magnetic field.. More is the induced emf. Now to obtain a high emf in the secondary coil it is obvious that an increase in the number of turns in the primary coil is required as that would increase the magnetic field and hence in turn would also increase the induced emf.

However, in all the places I have seen that the number of turns in the primary coil is quite less..
Why is this?

Comment: " Now to obtain a high emf in the secondary coil it is obvious that an increase in the number of turns in the primary coil is required as that would increase the magnetic field...." - Would it? I think you're assuming that the primary coil is being driven by a current source which forces the same amount of ac current through the primary coil regardless of how many turns it has.

Comment: Sir or ma'am please please can you answer it briefly

Comment: Take a look at this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/solenoid.html and this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/indsol.html. You want to increase the B-field of the (primary) coil by increasing the number of turns in it. But by doing so you also increase the (self) inductance of the coil. The B-field increases with N, the number of turns. But the inductance increases with $N^2$. So if you use a fixed ac voltage source, the current will drop as you increase N, and the B-field will go as $N/N^2$ which means it will drop, too.